# Why do I have close vote privileges, but no edit privileges?

Tags: bug, support, editing

I can vote to close any question, as well as reopen any question. I presume this is because no one on the site has more than 3,000+ reputation.

However, there are users with 2,000+ reputation, meaning I have privileges to close and reopen a question, but I don't have the edit privilege. I thought that closure was a privilege that came *after* editing.

Is this intended, or an oversight?

Note that I can also review in the Close votes Queue, and the Reopen votes Queue, but not the suggested edits queue.

Comment: Related: [Why is more reputation required to edit on beta sites than to vote to close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315947/295232)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [the privileges page](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), and you'll notice that all the rep thresholds are artificially lowered, while the site is in private beta. Particularly, here's where the two relevant privilege thresholds lie:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Specifically though, shouldn't they be swapped? Closing and reopening, in my mind, are harder to use privileges than editing. But if it's not a bug, that's okay with me.

Comment: I would say they're deliberately swapped, given that this phase is where y'all are defining what's on- and off-topic, and as such there's likely to be a lot more fast closing and reopening happening.